# SQL count() multiple where values

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, xampp

I want to count `VOTE1` and `VOTE2` and show in my demographics. if it's only where `VOTE1` it is working but if I add `VOTE2` value on the DataGrid is not showing:

```
jokenfindthis("SELECT 
                  ` PRK` as 'Purok'
                    ,COUNT(*)  as 'No. of households'  
                FROM `tblresidence` 
                where VOTE1 & VOTE2   ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'  
                GROUP BY `Purok`   ")
```

Here is the example code when `VOTE2` is not added:
[image: here are the example code when vote2 is not added.]

The code is working when only `VOTE1` is in the code:
[image: the code is working when only VOTE1 is in the code]

This is my ComboBox:
[image: this is my combobox]

My `VOTE1` and `VOTE2` ComboBox I want to count. The selection is YES or NO. I want to show the numbers of YES or NO:
[image: my vote1 and vote2 combobox i want to count. the selection is YES or NO. i want to show the numbers of yes or no.]

Comment: Your query make no sense where comes the Vote2 from?

Comment: Have you tried breaking the query into two parts. I guess that will do. As in ```VOTE1 = <value> AND VOTE2 =<value>```

Comment: hello i updated my question with more description pic i used to be more understandable. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly I think I only partially understand this question, so excuse me in advance. If you're trying to report the results of Vote1 and Vote2 separately then you'll need to split them in your select statement.

```
jokenfindthis("SELECT 
                  ` PRK` as 'Purok'
                    , sum(case when VOTE1 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "' then 1 else 0 end)  as 'No. of households - Vote 1'  
                    , sum(case when VOTE2 ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedValue & "' then 1 else 0 end)  as 'No. of households - Vote 2' 
                FROM `tblresidence` 
                where VOTE1 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'  
                      or VOTE2 ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedValue & "'  
                GROUP BY `Purok`   ")
```

If you're trying to count residences where either Vote1 or Vote2 meet your condition then I would try the following

```
jokenfindthis("SELECT 
                  ` PRK` as 'Purok'
                    , count(*)  as 'No. of households'  
                FROM `tblresidence` 
                where VOTE1 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'  
                      or VOTE2 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'  
                GROUP BY `Purok`   ")
```

Comment: hello! Thank you so much! this can be good option for me if i can't sum the vote1 and vote2 using only one combobox. thank you again for your great help.

Comment: Are you trying to count residences where either Vote1 = Yes or Vote2 = Yes?

Comment: Hello. Im trying to count all yes in vote1 and vote2 combobox and also the NO in vote1 and vote2. It can either be vote1 = yes or vote2 = no. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As pagalprogrammer mentioned, you probably want to break your `WHERE` statement into two parts:

```
jokenfindthis("SELECT 
                  ` PRK` as 'Purok'
                    ,COUNT(*)  as 'No. of households'  
                FROM `tblresidence` 
                where VOTE1 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'  
                      AND VOTE2 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'  
                GROUP BY `Purok`   ")
```

Comment: hello i just updated my question with pictures. the code above doesnt work

Comment: In your image `this is my combobox`, should `VOTE2` be listed somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

By selecting VOTE1 =  AND VOTE2 =  you are only going to see results where VOTE1 also equals VOTE2. Did you really want to do this?

where 
    VOTE1 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'
    OR VOTE2 ='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'

Comment: hi, vote1 and vote2 are my combobox. i just want to count the YES and NO of those boxes. add all the yes in VOTE1 and YES in VOTE2.